# Identifying duplicate fields and print both with awk

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, duplicate

I have a file with multiple columns and want to identify those where specific column values (cols 3-6) have been duplicated.

The following code finds the duplicates but I want to display both instances, not just the second. The other column values (cols 1, 2 and 7+) can be different between the 2 lines hence the need for me to view both instances.

```
awk 'seen[$3, $4, $5, $6]++ == 1' filename
```

Comment: `awk 'seen[$3, $4, $5, $6]++ >= 1' filename`

Comment: Still only shows the second instance - not both

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`uniq` is the correct tool for that:

```
uniq -D -f2 file
```

Where:

- `-D` - prints all duplicates
- `-f2` - avoid comparing the first 2 fields

**Edit:** If the fields 7 and above are not to be compared, you need `awk`:

```
awk 'n=x[$3,$4,$5,$6]{print n"\n"$0;} {x[$3,$4,$5,$6]=$0;}' file
```

- The array item `x[]` (columns 3-6) is checked. If it's already set run the part in `{...}` (in the same statement the `n` variable is set to the value of that array item)
- In the brackets `{...}`: The `n` variable and the current line `$0` are printed.
- Then we set the `x[]` array item for the next iteration to the current line contents, for later comparsion.

Comment: Wouldn't -f2 still compare columns beyond col6? Also, what if I need to compare non-consecutive columns?

Comment: Doesn't it presuppose that the file is sorted on fields 3 to 6 also?

Comment: The edited version has done the job. Thanks @chaos!