# Identifying duplicate fields and REMOVE both with awk

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, duplicate

Previously, I asked the question: [Identifying duplicate fields and print both with awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225418/identifying-duplicate-fields-and-print-both-with-awk).

I have a file with multiple columns and wanted to identify lines where specific column values (cols 3-6) had been duplicated.

An answer to this was `awk 'n=x[$3,$4,$5,$6]{print n"\n"$0;} {x[$3,$4,$5,$6]=$0;}' file`

I now have the problem that I want to remove ALL lines identified using the above code from the datafile, leaving only lines that were never duplicated.

I have tried to use `!=` instead of `=` but this gives the same result as = or returns 0 lines. I have also tried:
`awk '!seen[$3, $4, $5, $6]++' file` but this also keeps the 1st instance of the duplicate that I want removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you are looking for a solution from `awk`, if your intended outcome is the elimination of your duplicates and not necessarily via `awk` alone, try:

1. Firstly, ensure original input file is sorted, for example `sort unsorted_file > file`
2. Run the [awk command you previously found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225418/identifying-duplicate-fields-and-print-both-with-awk) for identifying duplicates within columns 3-6, and saving output to a file, for example `file_3-6_dupes`, on your command prompt:

```bash
$ awk 'n=x[$3,$4,$5,$6]{print n"\n"$0;} {x[$3,$4,$5,$6]=$0;}' file > file_3-6_dupes
```

3. Lastly, use `comm` to eliminate duplicates, saving the output to a file for example `file_3-6_uniques`:

```bash
$ comm -23 file file_3-6_dupes > file_3-6_uniques
```

### How this works

- a sorted input `file` is necessary because `comm` only works properly with sorted inputs
- the `awk` command won't alter the order of appearance of the duplicates it discovers, it merely follows whatever order they were in the original `file` so really it is just the original `file` that needs to be sorted in the first place
- by default `comm` outputs three columns:  lines only in file 1, lines only in file 2, and lines in common
- file 1: `file`
- file 2: `file_3-6_dupes`
- `-number` option specifies which of `comm`'s output columns to suppress,
- so `-3` means, suppress `comm`'s output column 3, what is common.
- `file_3-6_dupes` which contains just duplicates, was derived from `file`, so these duplicates are the only things that are found in common to `file` and `file_3-6_dupes`
- since we want the opposite of that, we just `-3` to suppress what is common, which are the duplicates
- on a minor note, we don't need an additional `-2` to suppress things that are only in file 2, there are none, in our case

So by combining the use of `awk`, the original file, and `comm`, we can achieve your goal of eliminating lines with column 3-6 duplicates.

### Tips

- if the original `file` came from Windows, the non-Unix line endings may prevent `comm` from working properly with the awk-generated `file_3-6_dupes`, so you could run `dos2unix` on `file` if you find `comm` not working, and retry the steps, then it should work